# Rails 3 or 4 - admin routing that maps to action with the name "admin_xxx"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Coming from CakePHP, It has this function that auto-maps action with `admin_` prefix to `/admin/...` route

So `Users#show` will map to `/users/1` while `Users#admin_show` will map to `/admin/users/1`

I know we can map it one by one like shown below:

```
scope "admin" do
  get "/users", to: "users#admin_index", as: "admin_users"
  get "/users/:id", to: "users#admin_show", as: "admin_user"
  ...
end
```

But that is not clean.

I can't seem to find this functionality in the official guide. So is there a way to do this without 3rd party plugin? If not, then what plugin do you recommend for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your admin controllers should be completely separate controllers from your frontend controllers, typically in an Admin namespace.

So your routes would be like:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :users
end
```

And your controller would be `Admin::UsersController` with the standard index/show/etc. actions.

For an example from the Rails docs:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing